# textview in a tablelayout cannot change width

Tags: android, width, tablelayout

If you look at the tablerow where there is the textview with ID 'correct'. 
If I enlarge the width in the code of this textview (also the case with some others), the width in the display does not enlarge. 
I don't see why. Anybody an idea? 
Here is my code.

If you look at the tablerow where there is the textview with ID 'correct'. 
If I enlarge the width in the code of this textview (also the case with some others), the width in the display does not enlarge. 
I don't see why. Anybody an idea? 
Here is my code.

Thanks

```
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:shrinkColumns="*">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="30dp">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewEmpty5"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_span="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/A"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:text="@string/btn1"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/B"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/btn1"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/C"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/btn1"/>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewEmpty6"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_span="1"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewEmpty1"
                android:layout_width="20dp"

                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_span="5"
                android:layout_height="30dp"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewEmpty7"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_span="2"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/equalsign"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/equalsign"
                android:layout_span="1"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/D"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:hint="Is gelijk aan"
                android:layout_span="1"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:imeOptions="actionGo"/>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewEmpty8"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_span="1"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewEmpty3"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_span="5"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/correct"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_height="30dp"/>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewEmpty2"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_span="1"
                android:text="@string/btn1"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/incorrect"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewEmpty4"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_span="5"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="30dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/verbetering"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_span="5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewEmpty9"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_span="5"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/add_unit_id2"
                android:layout_span="5"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use the tablelayout the right way.

The children of a TableLayout cannot specify the layout_width attribute. Width is always `MATCH_PARENT`. The width of a column is defined by the row with the widest cell in that column.
However, the layout_height attribute can be defined by a child; the default value is `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`. If the child is a TableRow, then the height is always `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`.  (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout)